# ffmpeg: [NULL @ 0x5578f5fc0580] Unable to find a suitable output format for '[out]' [out]: Invalid argument

Tags: ffmpeg

Trying to run the following ffmpeg transcoding and get the error msg: `[NULL @ 0x5578f5fc0580] Unable to find a suitable output format for '[out]' [out]: Invalid argument`

> ffmpeg -y -i
> /opt/bitnami/apache/htdocs/tmp/20211107100243-720aea3040844597987415efb09bcd48.mp4
> -async 1 -metadata:s:v:0 start_time=0 -vcodec libx264 -acodec aac -b:v 2500k -refs 6 -coder 1 -sc_threshold 40 -flags +loop -me_range 16
> -subq 7 -i_qfactor 0.71 -qcomp 0.6 -qdiff 4 -trellis 1 -b:a 128k -level 3 -pix_fmt yuv420p -movflags +faststart -strict experimental -vf [in]scale=810:1080 [out] -pass 1 -passlogfile /tmp/ffmpeg-passes6187a59ddd1a06cghb/pass-6187a59ddd236 -f mp4
> tmp/20211107100243-720aea3040844597987415efb09bcd48.mp4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the [link labels](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#Filtering-Introduction). Change `-vf [in]scale=810:1080 [out]` to `-vf scale=810:1080`.